# how to pass a list as argument in c#?

Tags: c#

`public string SendNotification(List<string> deviceRegIds, string message, string title, long id)` this is my method.

Can anybody please tell me the correct way to call it.
I tried this:

```
string wer;   
wer = SendNotification(List <string> qw ,"ds","cc",33);
```

but it is giving error that string is invalid term.
Any Help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have qw defined as a list of strings?

Comment: What is `qw`? An existing list? If so you can replace `List <string> qw` by `qw`.

Comment: `wer = SendNotification(qw ,"ds","cc",33);`

Comment: We can't answer until you express each dimension of your question. Don't know why people are assuming and posting answers

Comment: It is a simple syntatic error, Will you post a question at every error? Read docs, learn c#

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the list correctly like this:

```
string wer;   
wer = SendNotification(new List<string>(){"value1", "value2"},"ds","cc","33"});
```

OR:

```
wer = SendNotification(qw,"ds","cc","33"});
```

Comment: The first option is just sort of weird... especially considering it looks like OP already has a list.

Comment: I did not quite understand the parameters he tried, I fixed the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have qw defined as a list of string somewhere before.. 
you could simply do :

```
string wer = SendNotification(qw,"ds","cc","33"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong where you are passing in the string List. There are a few different ways to create a List.

You can initialize the list directly in your method call like this:

```
string wer = SendNotification(new List<string>() { "string1", "string2", "etc..."}, "ds", "cc", 33);
```

You can also initialize an empty list and add stuff to it later like this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("string1");
myList.Add("string2");

string wer = SendNotification(myList, "ds", "cc", 33);
```